# Trouble Executing SQL Commands on Enter Key Press in tkinter Application

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm working on a Python application using the tkinter library to create a GUI for interacting with a MySQL database. I want to execute SQL commands when the user presses the Enter key in an Entry widget. I've followed tutorials and examples, but I'm encountering issues getting it to work properly.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
import mysql.connector
import customtkinter as ctk
from settings import *

class Connection:
    def __init__(self, username, password, host, database) -> None:
        self.host = host
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.database = database

    def connectDb(self):

        self.myCon = mysql.connector.connect(
            user=self.username,
            host=self.host,
            password=self.password,
            database=self.database
        )
        # if (self.myCon.is_connected()): #  to check whether the connection is established or not
        #   print('db connection established')

    def executeCmds(self, commands):
        try:
            self.cursor = self.myCon.cursor()

            if ('select' in commands):
                self.cursor.execute(commands)
                for row in self.cursor.fetchall():
                    print(row)
            else:
                self.cursor.execute(commands)
                self.myCon.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def closeConnection(self):
        pass

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(fg_color=WHITE)
        self.title('SQL Connector')
        self._set_appearance_mode('dark')
        self.geometry('600x400')
        self.minsize(400, 300)
        # self.maxsize(800, 800)
        self.columnconfigure(index=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.rowconfigure(index=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), weight=1, uniform='b')
        self.minsize(400, 300)

        # Data
        self.entryVar = ctk.StringVar()
        self.labelVar = ctk.StringVar(value='SQL Connector')

        # widgets
        self.entry = Entry(self, entryVar=self.entryVar)
        self.entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3)
        self.button = Button(self, 'press For Commands')
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3, rowspan=2, pady=10)
        # Button(self, 'Button').grid(row = 3, column = 1, columnspan = 3)
        Label(self, self.labelVar).grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3)
        SlidePanelButton(self).grid(row=4, column=3, sticky='nsew')

        self.slider = SlidePanel(parent=self, startPos=0, endPos=-0.3)
        self.slider.place()

        # event binding
        try:
            self.entry.bind('<Return>', self.entryBinding)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        self.mainloop()

    def entryBinding(self):
        self.button.executeCmds()


class Entry(ctk.CTkEntry):
    def __init__(self, parent, entryVar):
        super().__init__(master=parent, corner_radius=0, textvariable=entryVar, fg_color=WHITE, bg_color=BLACK, text_color=BLACK)
        self.pack(expand=True)

class Label(ctk.CTkLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent, labelVar):
        super().__init__(master=parent, text='label', bg_color=BLACK, text_color=WHITE, textvariable=labelVar)
        self.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3, ipadx=10)

class Button(ctk.CTkButton):
    def __init__(self, parent, text):
        super().__init__(
            master=parent,
            corner_radius=0,
            text=text,
            command=self.executeCmds(),
            fg_color=GREEN,
            hover=True,
            hover_color=DARK_GREEN
        )
        self.parent = parent
        self.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3, rowspan=2)

    def entryData(self):
        commands = self.parent.entryVar.get()
        return commands

    def executeCmds(self):
        def wrapper():
            try:
                command = self.parent.entryVar.get()
                connection = Connection(username='', host='', database='', password='')
                connection.connectDb()
                connection.executeCmds(commands=command)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        return wrapper

    def animate(self):
        self.parent.slider.animate()

class SlidePanelButton(ctk.CTkButton):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(master=parent, text='Open Slider', fg_color=GREEN, hover_color=DARK_GREEN,
                         command=lambda: self.moveSlider(), corner_radius=0)  # type: ignore
        self.parent = parent
        self.place()

    def moveSlider(self):
        self.parent.slider.animate()
```

My goal is to allow users to input SQL commands into the Entry widget and then press Enter to execute the command. However, when I press Enter, I encounter errors like "TypeError: method() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" or "'MyCustomWidget' object has no attribute 'parent'".

I want to achieve the following:

1. Users enter an SQL command into the Entry widget.
2. When they press Enter, the SQL command is executed.
3. The Entry widget is cleared after the command is executed.

Could someone kindly guide me on how to correctly bind the Enter key press event to execute SQL commands within the context of my tkinter application? I appreciate any help or insights, including code snippets or explanations of where I might be going wrong.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you think your code isn't working? It looks like you've set up the binding properly.

Comment: uve got result, as soon as u pressed enter on the entry widget?

Comment: bro, so the thing is, when i press the enter, its not even working

Answer (score 0):

`entryBinding()` should accept an extra argument, the tkinter `Event` object. Also `self.button.executeCmds()` just return a wrapper function, so nothing will be executed.

Below is the modified `entryBinding()`:

```py
class App(ctk.CTk):
    ...
    def entryBinding(self, event): # added event argument
        func = self.button.executeCmds()
        # execute the wrapper function
        func()
```